# How to use 'row elements' of excel file(xlsx) in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, excel, import, casperjs

I want to import excel file (it consists of one column and many rows of string ) to my JavaScript and I'll use these strings elements of .xlsx to searching text automatically through CasperJS

How can I import excel file and make all of elements take turns applied?

Here is my code and I want to put the elements of excel file to "**something**"

```
casper.start('http://thehomepage.com/');
// start at homepage

casper.then( function (){
    this.sendKeys('#dicQuery','**something**');
    // I want to put my elements iteratelly
    console.log('entering text');
});
casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="field"]/a'), function(){
    console.log('click searching');
});
casper.then(function() {
    words = this.evaluate(getWords);
});

function createFinal(wordArray) {

    var out = [];
    // remove duplicating START
    var a = {};
    for(var i=0; i <wordArray.length; i++){
        if(typeof a[wordArray[i]] == "undefined")
            a[wordArray[i]] = 1;
    }
    wordArray.length = 0;
    for(i in a)
        wordArray[wordArray.length] = i;
     // remove duplicating END
    wordArray.forEach(function(my_word) {
        out.push({"moeum": "**something**", "word": my_word});
    });   // I want to put my elements in it iteratelly                 

    return out;                 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is xlsx file reader in PhantomJS (and therefore CasperJS), but you can save your xlsx file as csv. Since it is a simple text file, then you can read it and build your sheet yourself.

For example:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var sheet = fs.read("data.csv")
  .split("\n")
  .map(function(row){
    return row.split(";"); // or which even split character your have chosen for CSV
  });
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
sheet[rowIndex][colIndex]
```

Comment: thanks! In case of doing this iteratively, Can I use casper.then(function(){
                execute(casper, sheet[i], max);
            }); ???

Comment: I've not sure what `execute` does, but sure you can split the rows later or pass the row into some function.